# Como abrir un frame desde otro frame

Tags: java, eclipse

La función que quiero que realize el programa es que cuando se valide el usuario y contraseña se muestre el JFrame ventana. Pero no funciona

```html
package formularios;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import bean.Usuario;
import hilos.HiloBarra;
import mantenimientos.GestionUsuario;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class frmLogin extends JFrame {

 private JPanel contentPane;
 private JTextField txtUsuario;
 private JPasswordField txtContrasena;

 /**
  * Launch the application.
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    try {
     frmLogin frame = new frmLogin();
     frame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });
 }

 /**
  * Create the frame.
  */
 public frmLogin() {
  setTitle("Pantalla de acceso");
  setTitle("PANTALLA DE ACCESO");
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setBounds(100, 100, 556, 432);
  contentPane = new JPanel();
  contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
  setContentPane(contentPane);
  contentPane.setLayout(null);
  
  JLabel lblUsuario = new JLabel("Usuario:");
  lblUsuario.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
  lblUsuario.setIcon(new ImageIcon(frmLogin.class.getResource("/imagenes/user.png")));
  lblUsuario.setBounds(137, 169, 121, 51);
  contentPane.add(lblUsuario);
  
  JLabel lblContrasea = new JLabel("Contrase\u00F1a:");
  lblContrasea.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
  lblContrasea.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Neto\\Documents\\3ABM REYES\\iconos programa\\password.png"));
  lblContrasea.setBounds(137, 215, 126, 51);
  contentPane.add(lblContrasea);
  
  txtUsuario = new JTextField();
 
   
  txtUsuario.setBounds(257, 186, 139, 20);
  contentPane.add(txtUsuario);
  txtUsuario.setColumns(10);
  
  txtContrasena = new JPasswordField();
 
 
   
  
  txtContrasena.setBounds(257, 231, 139, 20);
  contentPane.add(txtContrasena);
  
  JButton btnIngresar = new JButton("INGRESAR");
  btnIngresar.setIcon(new ImageIcon(frmLogin.class.getResource("/imagenes/login.png")));
  btnIngresar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   
     ingresar();
    
    }
   
  });
  btnIngresar.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
  btnIngresar.setBounds(264, 316, 144, 44);
  contentPane.add(btnIngresar);
  
  JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("SALIR");
  btnNewButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(frmLogin.class.getResource("/imagenes/error.png")));
  btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    salir();
   }
  });
  btnNewButton.setBounds(123, 316, 110, 44);
  contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
  
  JLabel label = new JLabel(" ");
  label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(frmLogin.class.getResource("/imagenes/logo.png")));
  label.setBounds(178, -12, 379, 200);
  contentPane.add(label);
 }

 protected void ingresar()   {
  String usuario = txtUsuario.getText();
  String password = String.valueOf(txtContrasena.getPassword());
  
  GestionUsuario gestionUsuario = new GestionUsuario();
  Usuario usuario2 = new Usuario();
  usuario2.setNombre(usuario);
  usuario2.setPassword(password);
  Usuario usu = gestionUsuario.obtenerUsuario(usuario2);
 
  
  if(usu!=null){
  
  
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "BIENVENIDA");
   Ventana frame = new Ventana();
  frame.setVisible(true);
   this.dispose();
   
   
   
  }
  
 else{ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "ERROR DATOS INVALIDOS","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
 }
  
 }

 protected void salir() {
  System.exit(0);
  
 }
}
```

```js
package formularios;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Ventana {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        // create JFrame and JTable
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JTable table = new JTable(); 
        
        // create a table model and set a Column Identifiers to this model 
        Object[] columns = {"Id","First Name","Last Name","Age"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columns);
        
        // set the model to the table
        table.setModel(model);
        
        // Change A JTable Background Color, Font Size, Font Color, Row Height
        table.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        table.setForeground(Color.black);
        Font font = new Font("",1,22);
        table.setFont(font);
        table.setRowHeight(30);
        
        // create JTextFields
        JTextField txtTitulo = new JTextField();
        JTextField txtAutor = new JTextField();
        JTextField txtAno = new JTextField();
        JTextField txtGeneroMateria = new JTextField();
        
        // create JButtons
        JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Agregar");
        JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Borrar");
        JButton btnUpdate = new JButton("Actualizar");     
        
        txtTitulo.setBounds(20, 220, 100, 25);
        txtAutor.setBounds(20, 250, 100, 25);
        txtAno.setBounds(20, 280, 100, 25);
        txtGeneroMateria.setBounds(20, 310, 100, 25);
        
        btnAdd.setBounds(150, 220, 100, 25);
        btnUpdate.setBounds(150, 265, 100, 25);
        btnDelete.setBounds(150, 310, 100, 25);
        
        // create JScrollPane
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        pane.setBounds(0, 0, 880, 200);
        
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
        
        // add JTextFields to the jframe
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtTitulo);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtAutor);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtAno);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtGeneroMateria);
    
        // add JButtons to the jframe
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnAdd);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnDelete);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnUpdate);
        
        // create an array of objects to set the row data
        Object[] row = new Object[4];
        
        // button add row
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             
                row[0] = txtTitulo.getText();
                row[1] = txtAutor.getText();
                row[2] = txtAno.getText();
                row[3] = txtGeneroMateria.getText();
                
                // add row to the model
                model.addRow(row);
            }
        });
        
        // button remove row
        btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
                // i = the index of the selected row
                int i = table.getSelectedRow();
                if(i >= 0){
                    // remove a row from jtable
                    model.removeRow(i);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Error al eliminar");
                }
            }
        });
        
        // get selected row data From table to textfields 
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            
            // i = the index of the selected row
            int i = table.getSelectedRow();
            
            txtTitulo.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
            txtAutor.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
            txtAno.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
            txtGeneroMateria.setText(model.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
        }
        });
        
        // button update row
        btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             
                // i = the index of the selected row
                int i = table.getSelectedRow();
                
                if(i >= 0) 
                {
                   model.setValueAt(txtTitulo.getText(), i, 0);
                   model.setValueAt(txtAutor.getText(), i, 1);
                   model.setValueAt(txtAno.getText(), i, 2);
                   model.setValueAt(txtGeneroMateria.getText(), i, 3);**texto en negrita**
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Error al actualizar");
                }
            }
        });
        
        frame.setSize(900,400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       
        

 }
 
 public void setVisible(boolean b) {
  
  
 }


  
 }
```

Comment: [En esta otra pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37403/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-cerrar-una-ventana-en-java-y-que-aparezca-la-ventana-anterior-que-la) he dado una respuesta a lo que pides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En mi caso lo que siempre suelo hacer es mostrar un jdialog que sea modal con el login antes de mostrar los componentes que te interesen. Es decir muestra a un jdialog hijo del frame y bloqueas el frame hasta que se loguee.