# Cómo puedo cerrar una ventana en Java y que aparezca la ventana anterior que la llamó?

Tags: java

Una foto vale mas que mil palabras:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde la Ventana principal del programa, si haces clic al botón "Registrar usuario", la ventana principal se cierra con `dispose();` y te abre la Ventana Registrar usuario pero, y para lo contrario?.

Cómo cierro la **Ventana Registrar usuario** y que aparezca nuevamente la **Ventana principal**?. Quiero hacer eso porque en la Ventana principal tengo mas botones para otras ventanas con funciones diferentes, a lo mejor el usuario quisiera hacer mas cosas, ademas de registrar un usuario.

Espero puedan ayudarme, nunca había hecho esto en Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero, da igual que sea Eclipse que cualquier otro IDE, estás preguntando por Java.

Segundo, para solucionar lo que pides, puedes hacer un Manager, para gestionar qué ventanas usas, que es la opción más complicada si no sabes pasar por flujos ágilmente. Para una solución sencilla lo más fácil es que referencies la clase que llama (la ventana principal que pones), hasta la ventana nueva:

1. Lo puedes hacer en su constructor
2. Con un método `set` que establezca el JFrame que abrirá cuando des a un botón
3. La más bonita si sabes qué se debe abrir al cerrar la otra sería sobreescribiendo el método `dispose()` de la nueva ventana o creando un método `cerrar()` que haga lo que quieres y llamarlo desde el botón que cierre la nueva ventana.

Vamos que tienes muchas posibilidades, y más que no he puesto, piénsa en ello y prueba la que más te guste y si tienes algún problema pues haz otra pregunta más concreta.

#### EDITO PARA AÑADIR SOLUCION 3:

La solución tres sería así:

Dentro de tu código de la Ventana Principal:

```
//Nuevo método para conseguir el JFrame de la Ventana Principal
private JFrame getFrame(){
    return this;
}

//Botón para hacer el registro
btnRegistrarUsuario.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        VentanaRegistro vNueva = new VentanaRegistro(){
            //Con esto cuando llamemos a dispose de vNueva abrimos la principal
            @Override
            public void dispose(){
                //Hacemos visible la principal
                getFrame().setVisible(true);
                //Cerramos vNueva
                super.dispose();
            }
        };

        //Hacemos visible a vNueva
        v.setVisible(true);
        //Cerramos la principal
        dispose();
    }
});
```

Cuando se vuelva a abrir la principal estará como la dejaste.

Comment: como podría reescribir dispose()?, una pregunta me viene a la mente. El usuario hace login, si es Administrador, le aparecen todos los botones, si es Portero, solo le aparece 1 solo botón. Al hacer eso, sobreescribir dispose() para que aparezca la ventana principal, esa diferencia de rol se mantiene?, debo validar eso nuevamente?. No entiendo mucho la lógica se cerrar una ventana y que en la ventana principal se quede con los datos que tenía.

Comment: Te añadí el código para hacer la opción tres que elegiste.

Comment: una pregunta, y que debe de ir en el botón Cerrar de la Ventana Registrar usuario?.

Comment: agregué todo eso en la ventana principal pero, y en el cerrar que pongo?, porque cuando instancio la vprincipal me abre dos ventanas ;(

Comment: En la botón cerrar de la ventana de registro pones dispose(). El código esta comprobado.

Comment: vale, funciona. Es increible lo que hace un codigo corto. Podrias editar tu respuesta y explicar un poco mejor el codigo?, realmente no entiendo mucho cada linea con los comentarios que has agregado.

Answer (score 0):

Hay una manera que es mucho más sencilla. En la vista "DESIGN" del JFrame, seleccionas el JFrame (el espacio en blanco, no botones o etiquetas), y dentro de "Propiedades", en "defaultCloseOperation" seleccionar el evento que quieres que haga cuando se cierre el JFrame. Los eventos posibles son:

- HIDE. Oculta el JFrame y mantiene la aplicación en ejecución.
- EXIT_ON_CLOSE. Se sale de la aplicación. Todos los datos que se hayan metido se pierden. Es el que viene por defecto.
- DO_NOTHING. No hace nada.
- DISPOSE. Cierra esa ventana, pero mantiene la aplicación en ejecución. Se diferencia de HIDE en que con DISPOSE se libera memoria utilizada de usar esa ventana, mientras que con HIDE se mantiene en la memoria.

[image: Cerrar ventana sin terminar programa en JFrame]

En la vista "SOURCE" aparecerá de manera automática el cambio:

setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);